# Encrypt dictionary of objects based on "password" key in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, encryption

I'm working on a C# WinForms application that takes information from the user such as name, email, billing address, credit card, etc. Each set of all the information is stored in a Billing Account object (billing). I am storing all of the objects in a dictionary, and it works fine.

Now that I finished that, I want it to save the dictionary of billing accounts so that if the program is closed and opened back up again, their accounts will still be there. I need the information to be encrypted as well, because it holds sensitive information such as credit cards. Is there a way to encrypt and save the dictionary based on a "password" key so that it can be accessed later? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks so much!

EDIT: Just want to make clear that I'm only storing the information on the users computer. The only time it leaves is through an https connection no different than logging onto an online store and typing it in there.

EDIT 2: The information is only being stored on the user's computer where it has all of the defenses of the operating system's security. I just want to secure and hide it enough to give it a little bit of extra security and also to prevent just anyone from clicking on a text file and having the information in plain sight.

Comment: How are you storing this dictionary? in a file or in a database? or something else entirely?  Have a read about [PCI compliance](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/) because there may be legal requirements in your area when it comes to storing credit card numbers safely.

Comment: It's a desktop application so probably in a file on the user's computer. Is that okay?

Comment: On [Page 14](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_ssc_quick_guide.pdf), it's allowed to store them on encrypted file with secured encryption key. There are also security requirement on display and all. What will the data used on? To be printed or sent to another program? You might find CC tokenization as better alternative

Comment: The information will be used to contact a website (Not mine) and make purchases. The credit card information will be sent through an https POST request. I want the information to be stored on the user's computer so that it can be reused even after the program has been closed and reopened.

Comment: CC tokenization service should be simpler to use (and satisfy the security compliance). If the CC data are sitting on the computer the physical access must be secured (ie, unauthorized employee can't just sit there planting malware, keylogger or grab the harddrive away). The software must be designed to require (at least) username & password that aren't leaked, etc. Much cheaper to just use 3rd party service.

Comment: How do I go about doing that? I'd really rather program it myself rather than pay for a service though.

Comment: you can never beat an attacker with physical access to the machine ... you can only make his life harder...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 yes exactly and this is only saved to the users machine where they have all the defenses o the operating system's security. I just want to leave it mostly protected and unreadable so that the user's credit card numbers aren't in plain sight for anyone to take a look.

Comment: Remember, these are **legal requirements** for storage and use of credit card numbers. It's much more than just best practices; there are real penalties for failure to do this properly. But don't just take our word for it... we're just random people on the internet. If you don't already understand these rules and don't have someone who does that can advise you, you need to **STOP** what you're doing and take a step back until you are able to approach the situation more professionally. This may mean informing your boss/supervisor that you need help before you can proceed.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I appreciate the concern but I don't have a supervisor, this is an independent project. Also are there really legal requirements for just storing the information on the users computer and not transferring it anywhere?

Comment: @WaywardSemicolon Yes, there are. Credit card numbers are legally protected.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn aren't they also protected just by being on a secure operating system? If the hacker has access to the machine he can just go into chrome and view the stored credit cards there just as easily can't he? So am I liable for someone downloading malware that can install a backdoor or rootkit or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I would break this problem down in to 2 distinct parts:

### 1. How to securely store the user's password:

This is a fairly complex topic but there are lots of articles out there about it.. Here is the basic idea.

- Don't ever store the password. Instead store a hash produced by your
  password hashing algorithm, a suitably complex Salt and (depending on
  your hashing algorithm) store a number that is used for [Key
  Stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching).
- Use the password the user provides to try to re-compute the password
  hash using the stored salt and stretching number.
- If the hash matches what you stored.. then the password is correct!
  hooray, You can now use that password as part of your encryption key.

[Some reading material](https://blog.mking.io/password-security-best-practices-with-examples-in-csharp/)

### 2. Use that password as a salt to generate an encryption key:

Now honestly I dont know too much about this as previously I have relied on db-level encryption.

Perhaps someone can fill in some more information on that?

Here is an [MSDN article on generating encryption keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e9ft273(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: On a python program I once created I used a Vigenere Cipher to hide information based on a password, and then I stored it in a file with a key phrase included at the beginning. When the user tried to log in, it would decrypt it based on that password and then check to see if the key phrase was correct, which is similar to what you are saying. My point is that I don't need to store the password do I? I can just encrypt and decrypt based on a user entry. Or is that incorrect?

Comment: That can work I suppose, but keep in mind the best algorithms for hashing passwords are not necessarily the best algorithms for encrypting data and visa versa.  Potentially doing that method could leave your encrypted file open to brute force attempts at decrypting, since there is potentially a known key phrase to check for.  Also encryption/ decryption is performance oriented, and wont support key stretching.

Comment: Doesn't the file need to be encrypted either way?

Comment: Yes definitely. But you should take every precaution when storing credit card numbers.

Answer (score 0):

basically what you want to do is store information, in an encrypted form based on a password...

first of all some side notes:

- no matter how secure your crypto is, it will allways be as weak as the weakest link in the chain ... if your user has 123 as a password, well... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
- do not roll your own crypto ... you WILL screw up ... use standard libraries and well known algorithms

so where to start...

you have some password (pw) and some clear text information which will be represented as a byte array (data)

now find a library that contains PBKDF2 (**P**assword **B**ased **K**ey **D**erivation **F**unction **2**)

for c# that would most likely be the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`-Class in mscorelib's `System.Security.Cryptography`

if you can provide a machine and user dependant salt (s), and use a iteration count (c) that takes around a second on the targetplatform to complete (you will have to try around with the iteration count ... higher = better but slower... the higher this value is, the higher the calculation costs for an attacker to make one attempt on trying a password ... i'm pretty sure you can afford a delay of one or two seconds when the user enters his password ... for an attacker that means no longer try millions of passwords per second but merely a few, or he needs a lot of calculation units) ... *hint hint hint: c might be a variable you want to put in a .config file for easier changed depending on the machine the program is running on ... but be aware: change this after the key was first used and your data is pretty much garbage*

so what will be the result of PBKDF2? ... a byte array which will be our cipher key (k)

so ...
k = PBKDF2(pw,s,c)

technically the mentioned c# class expects you to call its constructor with the parameters and then call GetBytes(Int32) on the resulting object, providing how many *bytes* you want from PBKDF2 ...

so how big shall k be? ... depends on your cipher ... AES-256 for example needs 256 key bits, which is is a keysize unlikely to be bruteforced any time soon... that means you want 256 / 8 = 32 key bytes

so now we have a cryptographically usefull key k

now get your hands on a cipher to use it with, for example, said AES-256...

for c# one example would be System.Core's `System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider`

create an instance, provide k as the key, and now for the standard mode of operation (CBC, cipher block chaining) of that class, provide a random IV (Initialization Vector, just one blocklength, 128 bit/16byte in this case, of random data that is no secret and may safely be stored along with your ciphertext)

safe usage of the described class can be viewed in the msdn example code ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

please keep in mind that you will need the same IV to decrypt, so you need to save that... and no... do NOT hardcode a value

Comment: Where should I save the IV so that it is not easily accessed by an alleged attacker?

Comment: the IV is no secret ... there is no need to keep it in a secure place... just store it along with the ciphertext